# Norm of the solution of a Poisson equation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, poissons-equation

Let $\kappa$ be a linear contraction (operator norm at most $1$) on a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space $H$, $L:=1-\kappa$ and $f,g,\tilde g\in H$ with $$Lg=f=L\tilde g\tag1.$$ Are we able to show that $\left\|g\right\|_H^2-\left\|\kappa g\right\|_H^2=\left\|\tilde g\right\|_H^2-\left\|\kappa\tilde g\right\|_H^2$?

Clearly, the claim is trivial if $L$ is injective. If necessary, feel free to assume that $\kappa$ is self-adjoint. In that case, $$\left\|g\right\|_H^2-\left\|\kappa g\right\|_H^2=\langle f,(1+\kappa)g\rangle_H\tag2.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me use $K$ instead of $\kappa$. Assume $K$ self-adjoint. Then
$$\begin{split}
\|g\|^2-\|Kg\|^2&=\langle f,(I+K)g\rangle\\
&
=\langle (I-K)\tilde g, (I+K)g\rangle\\
&=\langle (I+K) \tilde g,(I-K)g \rangle\\
&
=\langle (I+K)\tilde g, f\rangle\\
&
=\|\tilde g\|^2 - \|K\tilde g\|^2
\end{split}$$

Comment: Ah, trivial from what I already had in $(2)$. Just to be sure: The assumptions (including the self-adjointness) do not already imply the injectivity of $L$, do they?

Comment: No, they are valid for $K=I$ or $L=0$, too.